# How can I mount an ISO file?

Tags: 14.04, mount, iso

I'm trying to open an ISO file, but not having any luck.

So far I have tried:

- Gmount (it doesn't seem to work because it says the folders aren't empty?
- furiusisomount not available for Ubuntu 14.04
- Archive Mounter (nothing happens when I right click the ISO and open with Archive Mounter)
- FuseISO - I right click file MOUNT ISO.. nothing happens.

So I try the **old fashioned way** with command line:

```
$ sudo mount -o loop /media/user/Jupiter-8/files/butterfly.iso /media/iso
mount: you must specify the filesystem type
```

Output of `file /media/user/Jupiter-8/files/butterfly.iso`:

**FoxPro FPT, blocks size 0, next free block index 1380078928**

What should I do?

Comment: `-t iso9660`, if it's a normal ISO

Comment: im sorry i dont understand. Does this go before the command i put in or after?

Comment: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop5,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

Comment: What kind of iso file is `butterfly.iso`? Did you check that the download was good? Can you check it via cloning to a USB drive or DVD disk?

Comment: It's a game… I'm not sure what you mean by checking it via cloning though…

Comment: I see. It is not a normal [linux] iso file, and might not be possible to mount by the mount command. You can 'burn' to a DVD disk with for example `k3b`. Then the game *might* work, when connected to a computer running Windows (if there is no protection against copying).

Comment: I dont really want to play the game. I need access to the files.

Answer (score 4):

### Mounting

Loop mount works without specifying the file system, when you mount 'normal' linux iso files like Ubuntu family iso files.

```
$ sudo mount -o loop ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso /mnt/lp1
[sudo] password for sudodus: 
mount: /dev/loop0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
```

It might help to specify the file system with some other kind of iso file. The file system may not be `iso9660`, but `udf` or something else. You have to guess here unless you clone the iso file to a USB pendrive or burn it to a DVD disk and look at that with `sudo lsblk -f`

```
$ sudo umount /mnt/lp1
$ sudo mount -t iso9660 -o loop ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso /mnt/lp1
mount: /dev/loop0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
```

### Checking

```
$ df -h /mnt/lp1
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0      1,5G  1,5G     0 100% /mnt/lp1

$ sudo lsblk -f /dev/loop0
NAME  FSTYPE  LABEL                    UUID                     MOUNTPOINT
loop0 iso9660 Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS amd64 2016-07-19-21-27-51-00   /mnt/lp1

$ sudo lsblk -m /dev/loop0
NAME   SIZE OWNER GROUP MODE
loop0  1,4G root  disk  brw-rw----

$ ls -l /mnt/lp1
total 56
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root  2048 jul 19  2016 EFI
-r--r--r-- 1 root root   232 jul 19  2016 README.diskdefines
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root  2048 jul 19  2016 boot
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root  2048 jul 19  2016 casper
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root  2048 jul 19  2016 dists
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root  2048 jul 19  2016 install
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root 18432 jul 19  2016 isolinux
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 21439 jul 19  2016 md5sum.txt
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root  2048 jul 19  2016 pics
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root  2048 jul 19  2016 pool
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root  2048 jul 19  2016 preseed
lr-xr-xr-x 1 root root     1 jul 19  2016 ubuntu -> .
$
```

### An example with `udf`

```
$ sudo mount -o loop LXDE_on_Leap_42.1_openSUSE_by_kolAflash.x86_64-0.1.1.iso /mnt/lp2
mount: /dev/loop1 is write-protected, mounting read-only

$ sudo lsblk -f /dev/loop1
NAME    FSTYPE LABEL UUID                                       MOUNTPOINT
loop1   udf    CDROM 2015-11-10-19-42-39-00                     /mnt/lp2
```